# How to like youtube videos using curl?

Tags: curl, post, youtube

I'd like to like a YouTube video using curl.

What I have is the following POST request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=test&rating=like&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

How finally to POST with curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl -X POST <url>` will issue an HTTP POST request to `<url>`.